# Greek character in Beamer document title

Tags: math-mode, beamer, symbols, titles, greek

I need to include the Greek letter sigma in the title of my Beamer presentation. When I use `$\sigma$` to obtain the symbol  (which works fine in other LaTeX document titles), I receive the warning messages:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 28.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\sigma' on input line 28.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 28.
```

This appears to be happening whenever I use the math environment within the title, regardless of what text is within the `$ ... $` symbols. Note: the sigma symbol still appears in the PDF, but it worries me that it might cause a problem later on.

Is there any way to resolve these warning messages? Alternatively, is there another way to include the letter sigma without using the math environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks), which we use for both code and log messages (the formatting is often useful). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This happens because in general math mode symbols are not available for inclusion in PDF bookmarks, *etc.* One approach is to use `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\title{Some text \texorpdfstring{$\sigma$}{[sigma]}}
```

which will use `$\sigma$` in TeX and `[sigma]` for the bookmark. On the other hand, if you are using sigma for something non-mathematical, then consider using a UTF-8 engine (XeTeX or LuaTeX) and inserting the character directly.