# Any useful command to fix this error:LaTeX Error: Unicode character ⌊ (U+230A)

Tags: unicode-math, characters

I am using Arxiv template example of overleaflatex. Sometimes I got some errors that I regarding Unicode characters that can fix. In my research paper I have used the latex symbol `r_\ell`. I have got the bellow error  it asked  me to provide a definition with

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter  , The latex error is ⌊ (U+230A).
```

However, I have included all needed package but it can't be fixed. Any help ?

not set up for use with LaTeX.

```
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.245 ... \le 6$ we observe that $r_{\ell-1} = ⌊
                                                   r_{\ell}/10⌋$
You may provide a definition with
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Entering Unicode characters in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/entering-unicode-characters-in-latex) (blanket question but I think it's fine as a duplicate target)

Comment: Note: It seems, you are thinking, that `r_\ell` is the problem. The problematic source is immediately before the line break in the error message. So *not* `r_\ell` is the problem. The problem *is* the unicode symbol `⌊` (at the end of the code line before the line break in the error message).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why do you say you have included all needed packages?

⌊ is not set up for *pdflatex* (you have tagged unicode-math, but that is *lualatex*)

As the message says, add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{230A}{\lfloor}
```

If you are usng pdflatex. (Or configure the system to use `unicode-math`and `lualatex`)

Answer (score 0):

As, [David Carlisle's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668663/289820) suggested, the following solution

```latex
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{230A}{\lfloor}
```

works without errors only for **mathematical formulas**.

If you want to have it added for a regular text (like in code, for example), you need to provide the "**$**" signs, just to avoid errors about lacking a mathematical formula signs ($).

i.e.:

```latex
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{230A}{\ifmmode \lfloor \else $\lfloor$ \fi}
```

works for every type of text, checking for mathmatical mode (big thanks to [@Teepeemm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/107497/teepeemm) for pointing that out)

Comment: But then it will only work for regular text, and not for mathematical formulas.  To make it work in both, you'd need `\ifmmode`.  But I think I would argue that it would be better to have an error when you use a math symbol in text mode, instead of silently allowing that to happen.

Comment: @Teepeemm Corrected as you have suggested, Great thanks to you! Could you expand more on why would you argue on it? I got interested.

Comment: These kinds of "autocorrection" is not necessarily good, refer to [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Why are so many symbols restricted to math mode? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70629/why-are-so-many-symbols-restricted-to-math-mode)