# Using Greek Letters

Tags: letters, greek

For the following example I'm getting `Missing $ inserted...` with regard to the `\rho` command:

```
a tangible benefit from acquiring positive reputation that is not captured within 
\citet{d05a}, in particular, it implies that in this setting \rho rises over time.
```

I tried `$rho$`, as it seemed to be suggesting, but that just put the word rho in italics.

Comment: greek letters are "math"-objects. Hence you need to do `$\rho$` (remember the backslash). :)

Comment: `\(\rho\)` is the right thing: it's a math symbol and requires math mode. LaTeX experts will probably use `$\rho$`.

Comment: Absolutely amazing. I only started using LaTeX for the first time yesterday - talk about a steep learning curve! Thanks to both of you though, this has worked a treat!

Comment: @egreg, I believe `$...$` is (mildly) deprecated. At least I prefer `\(...\)` as it has clear open/close.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/how-to-typeset-greek-letters

Comment: @vonbrand [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode).

Answer (score 6):

If you can use unicode-enabled engines such as XeTeX or LuaTeX, you can simply add the greek letter ρ into the document.

If you stick to tex of pdftex as engines, you can find a way by the `inputenc` package, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc) you can find some help.

In all cases, `\(\rho\)` or `$\rho$` will give you a ρ in italics. If you need in upright shape, you can use the `upgreek` package for that.

Comment: Just as a bit more information: remember to use `$\uprho$` rather than `$\rho$` after declaring the `upgreek` package (or the `\(\)` syntax as you desire).