# How to make theta symbol?

Tags: symbols

I try to write `(x,y,\theta)` but I get an error that says, "Missing $ inserted". If I remove `\theta` the error disappears. What is wrong?

Comment: `\theta` is a macro that need to be used within a math-mode. So you should use `$(x,y,\theta)$` to create an in-line mathematical environment (or replace `$`s by `\[` (opening) and `\]` (closing) for centered formula in a new line). Or if you don't want to use math-mode, you can have a look on [how to use greek letters in text without changing to math mode](http://texblog.org/2012/03/15/greek-letters-in-text-without-changing-to-math-mode/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\theta` is defined in math mode which is why TeX makes the announcement `$ inserted`.
If what you type is indeed a formula, surround it with `$`:

```
$(x, y, \theta)$
```

If it is normal text, the correct input depends a bit on whether you use (normal) (La)TeX or e.g. XeLaTeX (or other compiler that understands unicode input).
XeLaTeX allows for direct Unicode input and does not need `\theta`.

See also [How to typeset greek letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/how-to-typeset-greek-letters)

Comment: Does it also applies for x of t when I want to writ in in text, like this:   $x_{t}$ ? 
I'm using sharelatex

Comment: In general, all mathematical formulae should be typeset using `$...$` (or `\( ... \)`) when within a stretch of text or, if they are longer, within an environment such as `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.
For some more info and help, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics might be helpful

Comment: Thnaks. But it does not work for equation for me when I try this: \begin{equation}
   $ \overline{bel}(x_{t}) = p (  x_{t}  \textbar z_{1:t-1} , u_{1:t} ) $
\end{equation}
If I remove $..$ then I get worming: Command \textbar invalid in math mode on input line 12

Comment: @naman Your last comment seems to be asking a new question, so please do that: ask a new question. This time include a MWE (a very small complete document with just the one mistake). Format it as code so we can cut and paste it and fix it.

Comment: @naman Within the equation environment you don't need $ since     \begin{equation} switch on the math mode. The warning you get only means that the \textbar command is not for use in math mode.

Answer (score 2):

You need math mode: $(x,y,\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be at math mode to enable Greek letters and other math symbols. you should write:
`$(x,y,\theta)$` or  `(x,y,$\theta$)`.
I recommend the first version as it also write the x and y with a math type font, the same used on the equations.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your answer adds nothing new to the already existing answers.