# Clarifications about using Greek

Tags: pdftex, greek

This helps, but not entirely.

`https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/how-to-typeset-greek-letters`

`Package greek-fontenc Error: character �\GenericError {(inputenc)
    }{Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "91}`

MWE

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english,german,french,dutch,italian,spanish,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{polutonikogreek}(Εὐχολόγιον τὸ μέγα σὺν ϑεῷ ἁγίῳ)\end{otherlanguage} 1873 – большой, и \begin{otherlanguage}{latin}Liturgia Graeca\end{otherlanguage} \begin{otherlanguage}{polutonikogreek}(Μικρὸν εΰχολόγιον σὺν ϑεῷ ἁγίῳ)\end{otherlanguage} 1872 - малый. Который для Вас предпочтительнее?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless you need to submit to a site that *only* uses PDFTeX, it’s so much simpler to use `fontspec` and Unicode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `ϑ` (U+0391 GREEK SYMBOL THETA) instead of `θ` (U+03B8 GREEK SMALL LETTER THETA).

Add an equivalence for the symbol (or use the letter). Using U+0391 won't get you the “open theta”; the glyph depends on the font.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,english,german,french,dutch,italian,spanish,russian]{babel}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03D1}{\texttheta}

\begin{document}

\begin{otherlanguage}{polutonikogreek}(Εὐχολόγιον τὸ μέγα σὺν ϑεῷ ἁγίῳ)\end{otherlanguage} 
1873 – большой, и \begin{otherlanguage}{latin}Liturgia Graeca\end{otherlanguage} 
\begin{otherlanguage}{polutonikogreek}(Μικρὸν εΰχολόγιον σὺν ϑεῷ ἁγίῳ)\end{otherlanguage} 
1872 - малый. Который для Вас предпочтительнее?

\end{document}
```

[image]