# Why are text Greek glyphs different from mathematical Greek in Computer Modern?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts, latin-modern, computer-modern, newcomputermodern

Why are text Greek glyphs different from mathematical Greek in New Computer Modern, Latin Modern and Computer Modern fonts? The New CM comes with its own text Greek glyphs while for text Greek matching CM/LM, the fonts mentioned in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/how-to-typeset-greek-letters) were suggested. Text Greek matches math Greek for Stix2, Libertinus, Concrete, XCharter, EBGaramond, etc. but not for CM/LM/NCM.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \noindent New Computer Modern\\\\
    Text Greek upright: αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω\\
    Text Greek italic: \textit{αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω}\\
    Math Greek upright: \(\symup{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega}\)\\
    Math Greek upright: \(\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega\) \\

    \setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

    \noindent STIX2\\\\
    Text Greek upright: αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω\\
    Text Greek italic: \textit{αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω}\\
    Math Greek upright: \(\symup{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega}\)\\
    Math Greek upright: \(\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon \zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi \omega \pi \rho \sigma \phi \psi \tau \omega\) \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: it's just a personal choice of the designer, but the original cm only had math Greek, text Greek in similar style designed years later by different people, so it's perhaps not surprising there is more difference there. There is usually some difference, even for Latin eg a math italic v is not the same as a text italic v in most font sets

Comment: @Mico no :-). Just a curiosity. I like the NCM font and was only slightly irked that the text and the math don't match, just for this font. Personally, I find it odd if I see non-matching fonts in a document.

Comment: I think the more appropriate question for this site would have been 'Is there a way of using the math Greek letters of NCM for text?', with proper spacing.