# bookmark language isn't Greek {LyX}

Tags: lyx, bookmarks, greek

I am using LyX in order to write my thesis in Greek Language.
When I press the preview button on LyX, everything is ok with the greek language on my thesis except the bookmarks on the side of pdf. They aren't in Greek ... although table of contents is in Greek.

I attach a screenshot in order to understand what's my issue:

[image: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/6858/screenshotfrom201211131.png]

How can i fix this ?

Comment: See also (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41614/8272

Comment: @NikosAlexandris I see your point, but I guess the Lyx-specific element makes this a related rather than duplicate question.

Comment: @Joseph already taken care in the other question  :-)

Comment: @Joseph o-kay, it was easy to adapt the info into a LyX example (in the past, I mean) -- however, now added a LyX ready-to-use example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44130/8272

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that bookmarks do not know about TeX fonts. The Greek in the question is very likely based on font encoding, using Greek characters instead of the standard Latin alphabet and ligatures for generating accents. These are features of TeX's stomach. Bookmark strings, however, are simple text strings. Mainly only TeX expansion (TeX's mouth) is available for processing bookmark strings. Example, if the code for processing bookmarks in `hyperref` gets the character `C`, it does not know which font is used in TeX to typeset this glyph, neither it does know the language. Based on the features of font encoding and ligatures a string might contain many `C`, but meaning different glyphs.

### Ways to get Greek bookmarks

Bookmarks strings can be encoded in `PDFDocEncoding` or `Unicode`. For Greek `Unicode` is needed (regardless of input encoding) in all cases:

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}% or pdfencoding=auto
```

- Package `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdef` directly supports UTF-8 of `utf8.def` or `utf8x.def`. If UTF-8 is not an option for all the Greek text, then it can be limited
  to bookmarks:

  ```
  \section{\texorpdfstring{<Greek text>}{<UTF-8 for bookmarks>}}
  ```
- LuaTeX or XeTeX have native support for UTF-8/Unicode. These big chars (with character codes greater than 127) are also recognized and supported by `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdef`.
- If markers for the Greek stuff can be introduced inside the bookmark strings:

  ```
  \section{\texorpdfstring{...}{...<BeginGreek>...<EndGreek>...}}
  ```

  then it would be possible to catch the partial Greek strings and transform them
  to a form that is supported for bookmarks (via an expandable implementation or using the post-processing hook). But it quickly becomes nasty, if the Greek stuff is nested or includes Latin fragments (via `\ref`, …). Also the whole translation process from Greek in Latin form to real Greek has to be implemented.
- Short Greek stuff can also be set by using `\unichar` with the Unicode number
  in the second argument of `\texorpdfstring`. But for long texts this method is not very convenient.

Comment: First thanks for your answer !
Because i am using Lyx can you tell me exactly what should i paste on preamble to fix it ?
I tried the commands you gave me but nothing happened , only errors :( Sorry but i dont know so much yet about Latex ..

Comment: @ALdaperan As far as `hyperref` is concerned, UTF-8 seems the best way to proceed. Otherwise I can't help much, because I am not an expert for Greek or Lyx.

Comment: I paste and save \usepackage[unicode]{hyperref} on Lyx's preamble and then when pressing preview pdf I get an error saying : http://pastebin.com/ivd3Gae5

Comment: @ALdaperan As you can see, option `unicode` is already be loaded. Thus there is no need for another `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`. Then you need fonts and input method that do not rely on putting Greek characters at Latin character positions and using ligatures for the diacritics.